# How about sequence of newline symbols in non-text format files?

Tags: assembly, x86, newline, x86-16, emu8086

so far I've been practicing with assembly IBM 8086 architecture and I've received task to write a program which exchanges any 2 lines of file. (I give data file name and no. of those 2 lines through parameters). The algorithm of my program is as follows:

1) I'm using limited size buffer (for instance 20 byte size buffer). I read data from file to this buffer, constantly checking the value of ax register if the end-of-file is reached.

2) I'm passing this buffer to the procedure which checks for 13d symbol  (CR ASCII code) and passes elements of buffer to the new write-to-file buffer and if the symbol 13d is detected so then passing to write-to-file buffer stops and new line trigger variable is set to 1. Then if this newline 13d symbol is found, I call another procedure which returns file pointer to correct position (since I use custom-size buffers, I may find 13d symbol in the middle of buffer, so I need to reset pointer to correct new line).

So my program seems to be working correctly with .txt files, but when I try to exchange 2 random lines of, for example, .exe or .jpg file, and then exchange the same lines again I cannot open that file, since OS says it is corrupted.

My question would be: is it okay to even try exchanging any 2 lines of non-text format file, then try to change them back and expect the new file to work properly? Should this concept theoretically work? Or due to various different new line sequence interpretations (CF+NL, NL+CF, etc...) it is okay that such converted program becomes corrupted?

In other words: what is the interpretation of new line symbols in non-text files? Are their sequence important to the correct program operation?

Thanks for your answers, If part of my code is needed in order to answer question, please note me about that.

Comment: If your method will make the file byte-for-byte identical to the original, it will work.  If not, it almost certainly won't.  This is assembly language; everything is just bytes, unless you read data through some library function that tries to normalize newlines for you.  I'd recommend using something like `md5sum` or `crc32` to hash the file contents, or just `diff` or `cmp` them against the original.  (Those are unix shell commands, but there are windows equivalents, and the names should be obvious anyway.)

Comment: Wait a minute, limited buffer size?  So when you find a "line", you're actually only going to move the preceding up-to-18 bytes?  Hmm, depending on how you implement it, that might not be a problem, if line-detection will be in the same state at the start of the newly-placed data.  I didn't read the details of your algorithm exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to exchange lines in non-text file. If you do the same thing twice, you should receive the same binary file.

You don't because some of these:

- your algorithm with limited buffer size is not handling the situation correctly? In binary files there's good chance to hit "lines" of 100k+ byte length.
- you are not using binary read/write API (impossible to tell from question)? The text API like Clib `fopen` with mode `"rt"` may convert some byte values, so the content of file will be damaged.

> what is the interpretation of new line symbols in non-text files?

The interpretation of new line symbols in binary files can be anything, including new line symbol (when used in string data), but from file system perspective it's just byte (`0`-`255`) value of `0x0D` and `0x0A`, like any other byte of the file.

Maybe try to find some extremely short binary file which fails (maybe some 4096B intros), and use hexview or binary diff to see where the file is corrupted and then during debugging try to figure out how that situation happened.

> Are their sequence important to the correct program operation?

Of course, if the original binary contains `0D 0A` inside the machine code, then replacing it by `0D` only or flipping the two to `0A 0D` will destroy the original machine code instruction. If you damage the data section only, the program may still somehow work with damaged data, but changing code randomly would require big amount of luck to end with something working almost like original.

---

After seeing some code: it looks like `int 21h` file handler services are used, so the `int 21h` itself works with binary content of files (no conversion).

Any file damage is done by the application code itself. So you have to debug your algorithm and find out where it fails, then fix it.

Comment: It's actually more like the other way around... the files are files, binary streams of bytes. Then the program code interprets some of those binary files as text files, but that's code-dependent interpretation of the file content byte data, [common] file system is not aware of any text files, treats them the same as any other file on the storage medium.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, however, I would be very delighted if you found moment to get a glimpse on my 2 procedures (first one processes each buffer and second moves read file pointer): http://pastebin.com/v4vyBFBU (I'm working with basic 8086 assembler instruction set, no special API's). With those functions I get correct answer with text files, however, with other formats there is a complete nonsense. Bu as you mentioned sequence is important, it is not rational to expect file not to corrupt when executing these procedures, is it? :)

Comment: @KasparasTaminskas there's not enough code to decide whether it is correct... But some parts are suspicious, for example in `Rodykles_Perkelimas`: `cmp nuopabaigos, 3` `jb sitas` `cmp nuopabaigos, 0` .. when `(nuopabaigos == 0)`, the `jb` will jump already, so that second cmp is useless. And your `cx:dx` usage suggests you will fail when the distance between new-line character is over 64k, which may easily happen with big binary files like modern `.exe`. Overall I didn't manage to understand your algorithm, sorry.

Comment: @KasparasTaminskas you may actually want to redesign your algorithm? I would make it two pass, first: read the file first trough small (4k?) buffer and just store new line positions (I mean those requested to exchange) with dword indexes. You end with four file indexes from1-to1, from2-to2. Second pass: copy the file up to from1, then copy part from2-to2, then copy part to1-from2, then copy from1-to1 and finally append everything beyond to2. Use two files (copying from source to target), as overwriting in place the original file would require much more logic and buffering. Sounds simpler to me

Comment: It's not efficient, but as long as we are talking about MiB size of files, those are on modern OS cached in memory anyway, so two pass will lose little time by re-reading the whole file again. In case of 100+MiB files it would be more efficient to do clever single pass, but then again this is some exercise, not a real tool (and for DOS), so keeping it simple may be "good enough". The main challenge in my suggestion should be to create correct "`copy(dword from, dword to)`" subroutine. And maybe to calculate from/to correctly in first pass.

Comment: thank you for dedicating your time to help me, well I still have very basic assembly knowlegde and to be honest it is academical exercise, our lecturer requested us to use tiny buffers ~ 10-20B of length and make the program work at least with 4-5MB size files. In our course we use only 16b architecture registers. However I completed my task with .txt file as an example, since it is easier to track bugs, but now I'm facing struggle with binary data when passing other file formats. In this picture I tried to depict how I imagined my algorithm: http://prnt.sc/dadta8. Let me know if you got it.

Comment: About pic: I probably did got that part, but I have no idea how you use that to swap the lines, that was puzzling me. At least now I fully understand what you are doing, you reset the file pointer to the beginning of next line. Still with 10-20B buffer and 4-5MiB files the important part is how to swap, and I don't see how you can do it without two files, because when the line to swap is longer than your buffer, you can't store it in memory. So in-place overwrite is ruled out. Also 4-5MiB size requires you to manage file offsets as 32b `dword`. So in 16b you must build these from two 16b word.

Comment: @KasparasTaminskas so I do think the two-pass solution creating copy of file (with swapped lines) would fulfil those requirements. About bugs in the code you posted - hard to say, it probably almost does what you want (maybe fails in some corner cases, try for example file of `0A` bytes only), so I'm afraid most of the bugs are hidden in the upper level usage of those procedures. I don't want to trace it in my head properly, as it's missing too many parts, and it makes my in-head CPU very slow, reporting the missing parts after each "step".. tiresome.

Comment: I do actually use 2 files. I get info to the buffer from data file and at the same time I create and open results file at the beginning of the program. So my swaping goes like that: 1) I read&write to results file all data until the smaller line, which I need to exchange 2) I only read till bigger line's beginning 3) So now I'm reading this bigger line and writing it to results file (in smaller line's place), at the same time checking if I haven't hit newline to stop writing. 4) Now I open data file again and only read until the end of smaller line.

Comment: 5) In this step I both read&write until I reach the beginning of bigger line. 6) I open data file once again and only read till the beginning of smaller line. 7) Now I both read&write that smaller line in bigger line's place at results file. 8) I only read till the end of bigger line. 9) The rest data should be read&written until the end of file. So I use these steps as my basic algorithm.

Comment: Ok, your high level algorithm is correct, but you already has triple pass, so I think single pass to extract offsets and then seeking to copy correct part of file would be just as bad as yours, or better. If your code doesn't work, there's some bug(s) in it, so debug it. Focus at first at short line corner cases (exchanging lines 3 with 4 (zero length between parts), having zero length lines (only `0A`), exchanging first line with last line (zero length start of file, zero length end of file), etc.. then focus on long lines, and over 64k boundaries situations. Use binary diff on files.

Comment: Now I fully got your two-pass solution, thank you one more time! It should definitely be more effective!

Comment: By the way, If I receive, for instance the offset of required line number position in DX(upper) and AX(lower), how can I write from the beginning of file, till this offset? Since int 21h 40h function requires the offset of specific buffer to be declared in DX.

Comment: @KasparasTaminskas did you figure it out, or should I help you? (sorry for not answering, I was not in mood). In short, your question doesn't make much sense, you have ~20B buffer, so offset and length of buffer is fixed. What you do is copy 20B from source file to target file (calculating length of copied bytes in 32b counter) until you are <=20B ahead of target, then you copy only so much. Then you "seek" in source file to new 32b offset, take another 32b offset as target, and copy per 20B (or less) again till you hit new length target. 32b math is required only for seeking and counting/cmp.